# Meteor: Finding an object from a collection by _id

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to find an object by _id with Meteor.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Meteor.publish("gifts", function(gid) {
  console.log("Looking for "+ gid);
  var gifts = Gifts.find({_id: gid}).fetch();
  console.log("Result: " + gifts);
  return gifts;
});
```

This is the output:

> Looking for f1790caa-7a10-4af5-a01c-e80bb2c2fd55 Result:

If I take out the query:

```
Meteor.publish("gifts", function(gid) {
  console.log("Looking for "+ gid);
  var gifts = Gifts.find().fetch()[1];
  console.log("Result:" + gifts._id);
  return gifts;
});
```

The object is in the array, and the _id is the same as above.

> Looking for f1790caa-7a10-4af5-a01c-e80bb2c2fd55 Result:
>   f1790caa-7a10-4af5-a01c-e80bb2c2fd55

Also, if I execute the find in a mongo console, I find the object:

```
> db.gifts.find({_id: 'f1790caa-7a10-4af5-a01c-e80bb2c2fd55'});
{ "name" : "A new gift", "_id" : "f1790caa-7a10-4af5-a01c-e80bb2c2fd55" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you insert the document from?  MongoDB treats strings and objectIds differently, and it looks like there is currently a bug in Meteor that does not handle objectIds correctly.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Surprising that something as basic as this is not working, even given the early stage Meteor is in.

Comment: In meteor version 1.4, the behaviour can still be observed (I ran in the same pitfall). The issue linked by @shelman recommends using `meteor shell` instead of  the mongo console.