# Meteor sort collection random

Tags: sorting, random, meteor

I want to get a randomly sorted set from a Meteor collection. What is the best/most efficient way?

[Mongo options are controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336361/get-random-document-from-a-meteor-collection).

I am currently using [underscore _.shuffle](http://underscorejs.org/#sample) which is quite neat, eg:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return _.shuffle(Meteor.users.find().fetch());
  }
});
```

I use Jade, so maybe there's an option at the templating level?

Comment: Question: Since you're using an array in your template rather than a cursor, is it still reactive?

Comment: @Kyll, yes, but the entire helper will be recalculated if updates to the collection is made, so no nice fine-grained updates, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: this is the best solution I have found, I think there is not a better way of achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Lodash _.shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs#shuffle), like so:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return _.shuffle(Meteor.users.find().fetch());
  }
});
```

As hilarious as that might seem, there *is* a difference under the hood:

**Underscore** ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js))

```
_.shuffle = function(obj) {
  var set = isArrayLike(obj) ? obj : _.values(obj);
  var length = set.length;
  var shuffled = Array(length);
  for (var index = 0, rand; index < length; index++) {
    rand = _.random(0, index);
    if (rand !== index) shuffled[index] = shuffled[rand];
    shuffled[rand] = set[index];
  }
  return shuffled;
};
```

**Lo-Dash** (*slightly modified for ease of comparison*, [source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js))

```
_.shuffle = function(collection) {
  MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH = 4294967295;
  return sampleSize(collection, MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH);
}

function sampleSize(collection, n) {
  var index = -1,
      result = toArray(collection),
      length = result.length,
      lastIndex = length - 1;

  n = clamp(toInteger(n), 0, length);
  while (++index < n) {
    var rand = baseRandom(index, lastIndex),
        value = result[rand];

    result[rand] = result[index];
    result[index] = value;
  }
  result.length = n;
  return result;
}
```

You can take a look at [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore) for a more in-depth look at comparing the two libraries.

Both, Underscore and Lo-Dash, use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which you'd have a hard time doing "better" than.