# Meteor can't find by id in a Mongo.Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm trying to select a record by it's `_id`, but it's not working.

I'm having the same problems in the javascript console as in the Meteor code, so I'll run through an example in the console for simplicity.

I have two `Article`s in my collection. I'm publishing this collection from the server:

```js
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish('articles', function articlesPublication() {
    return Articles.find();
  });
}
```

And subscribing to it on the client:

```js
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('articles');

  return {
    articles: Articles.find().fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

I can verify that these are getting to the client with `Articles.find().fetch()` in the console:

[image: Articles.find().fetch()]

From examples online, it looks like I should be able to do `Articles.find({_id: id})` or `Articles.findOne(id)`, but nothing works:

[image: Articles.find(id) doesn't work in the console]

I *can* `find` and `findOne` by any other attribute, though. `Articles.findOne({title: "Dog eats Poop"})` correctly returns the record:

[image: findOne with the title attribute works]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly after typing this out I stumbled on [an old StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410993/meteor-finding-an-object-from-a-collection-by-id) that pointed to [a Meteor issue that was closed in 2013](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61) that records created in the `meteor mongo` console treat strings and `Mongo.ObjectId`s differently.

So I tried `Articles.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID("572bdb811ab1829622aeee78"))` instead of `Articles.findOne("572bdb811ab1829622aeee78")` and it worked:

[image: casting the id as a Mongo.ObjectID works]

So... what the heck. None of the example code shows the need to cast ids to a `Mongo.ObjectID`, and the issue that brought this up originally was closed three years ago.

Comment: Holy hell, THANK YOU!  I was pulling my hair out over this for hours, trying to figure out why everything was silently failing.  Brilliant work, man.